# Struggling to describe the language that this pushdown automaton represents

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Given this pushdown automaton :
[image]

I am trying to describe the language that this represents.

My analyze yet:

the numbers of a at the start will need to be the same that as the end.

Also, the starting letter if there's no a, will be one b.

Also, the last letter before the ending a's will be a b

Now I struggle with the middle loop ( state 3 and 4 ) I am not sure on how to analyze and represent it.

For now i have something that looks like this:

$a^n b(b^*aa^*bb^*)^*a^n :n \in\mathbb{N}$

But I am pretty sure it's not good since I think I need to have a relaiton between the exponent ( just like the $a^n$) the other exponent should also be represented by a letter but I can't seem to understand the pattern and relations here.
Just to give you an example i need something that could look like this :
$$
L=\left\{a^{m} b^{m} c^{n}: m, n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge m \geq n\right\}
$$

If this can help I figured some words that can be accepted : babb , aabaaababaa

Could anyone help me figure this out and how to approach it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language L is , L = { a^n b (a* b)*  a^n , n ≥ 0 }

We can see how the number of as at begging and end of the string must match from the transitions a,ε,c and a,c,ε , this is why we have a^n at begging and end

After the first a^n , the transition b,ε,ε shows that there comes a b

Now we arrive arrive at state 3 , we consider states 3 and 4 , once you enter 3 you are left with 2 options :

1. go from 3 to 3 , which is b , the same as a^0 b
2. go from 3 to 4 , loop on 4 if you want , then go back to 3 , which is a^+ b

now  you can do 1 or 2 , hopefully you can see that 1 U 2 is a^0 b U a^+ b =  a* b (this is why we wrote b as a^0 b) , and this can be repeated as many times as we want since after 1 or 2 we return back to 3 so we arrive at (a* b)*

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, i am not sure to understand your explanation with a^o what does o mean ? Also, i am not sure to understand the middle part (a* b)* So what i wrote in my edit isn't good ? Thanks.

Comment: You entered state 3 and eventually you are going to state 5 , before going to 5 what strings can you form , what options do you have ? you should reach a conclusion that they you can form  (a* b) * , we begin at 3 eventually we must return to 3 so we can head to 5 , what can we do to begin at 3 and return to 3 ?

Comment: Well we can read a b so we go from 3 to 3 , or we can read a^+ b, that is going to 4 looping if we want then back to 3 ( the a^+ is the same as aa* , where a is used to go from 3 to 4 then a* to loop on 4  ) so we know that to go from 3 to 3 we can do b U a^+ b , hopefully you can see that this is basically a* b , now a* b encapsulates all possible ways to go from 3 back to 3 again , after going back to 3 we can repeat the whole a* b as much as we want to go back to 3 again and so on , that's why we have (a* b) *

Comment: As for your grammar it fails to accept some strings like abba which should be accepted , also when  we have a symbol a , a^0 is the same as saying a repeated 0 times which is the same as ε , so b is the same as εb which is the same as a^0 b , if this point confuses you then don't worry about it as long as you understand the general idea , if anything remains unclear please feel free to ask

Comment: ok makes sens, but one last thing that i am not sure of is how is the b loop on state 3 represented in your language definition ? shouldn't it be a^n bb* (a* b)* a^n instead ? Thanks. Also idk if could help me to understand how to get the context-free grammar from this pushdown automaton i have an other open question but i don't really get the answer haha https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900560/give-the-context-free-grammar-that-generates-the-pushdown-automaton-language/3900623#3900623 THANKS again.

Comment: If you think about it you will find that b*(a* b)* is actually equivalent to (a* b)* , and so the grammar you provided is equivalent ( and thus correct ) to the one I gave , think about how (a* b)* can actually generate ε,b,bb, and thus it can generate b* , so you can use (a* b)* to generate b* then continue with other strings in (a* b) * , hopefully now you can see that (a* b)* is the same as b* (a* b) *

Comment: As for how to convert a PDA to a CFG this is already answered here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51658/how-to-convert-pda-to-cfg , it provides a standard way  converting PDAs to CFGs , however as mentioned , the grammar tends to be "gigantic , often with lots of useless productions and nonterminals" , the only way within my knowledge to produce a good grammar ( as close to minimal as possible ) is by understanding the language and writing the grammer (which gets easier with training and solving problems) , still this construction is important to prove the equivalence of PDAs  and CFGs

Comment: ok yea my teacher doesn't provide us a way to do it, so i guess we just go from the language description and try some things out, yea i understand that it's answered but if u wanna check my edit on the post about my CFG attempt it would be nice if u can tell if its good or not. If not it's all good u already helped a lot ! thanks